# How to do Google login inside electron js app using firebase

Tags: firebase-authentication, electron

[image]

I am facing this issue while trying to firebase Google login in electronjs app.

Answer (score 1):

It's not Firebase's problem, Google started blocking Google Log-ins in unsafe browsers(including Electron). So the workaround is faking Google to think that it's actually a safe browser(Mozilla).
The key part is the details.requestHeaders

```
session.defaultSession.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders((details, callback) => {
details.requestHeaders["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
callback({ cancel: false, requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders })
```